# Nuxt js radio button can't click but not disabled

Tags: typescript, vue.js, radio-button, nuxt.js

I have a radio button that is not getting checked.

It is working on other pages but i just can't seem to click it here.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">同居予定の有無</label>
                    <div class="radioCont">
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label"
                          ><input
                            id="yes"
                            v-model="properties.is_living_together"
                            class="form-check-input btn-group-toggle"
                            type="radio"
                            name="livingTogether"
                            value="1"
                            tabindex="7"
                          />有</label
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label"
                          ><input
                            id="no"
                            v-model="properties.is_living_together"
                            class="form-check-input btn-group-toggle"
                            type="radio"
                            name="livingTogether"
                            value="0"
                            tabindex="8"
                          />無</label
                        >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the properties

```
properties = {
.....
employer: '',
residence_card_number: '',
// @ts-ignore
is_living_together: ''
```

}

Any help appreciated.

Comment: the code seems to be fine. Are you sure there's no div overlapping those radio button?

Comment: You could also try to use the keyboard to toggle it and see what happens. I see you have a pretty high tabIndex defined. (I wonder why, normally you would want to leave it at default for accessibility reasons..) Anyway, you could easyily test if that works instead of a click.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Still can't fix.

Answer (score 0):

Click handler in the outer div modal was the cause.
Changed

```
<div
  id="statusConfirmModal"
  class="modal fade show"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="statusConfirmModal"
  @click.prevent.self="remove"
>
```

to

```
<div
  id="statusConfirmModal"
  class="modal fade show"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="statusConfirmModal"
  @click.self.prevent="remove"
>
```